# smoothly connect two meshes at a vertex - smooth transition between objects

Tags: vertices, solidify-modifier, smooth

I am trying to connect two meshes together. The connection is a single vertex. So:
Mesh>Merge>ByDistance

[image]

The problem occurs when I add the Solidify modifier (Simple/Thickness 0.3/Offset 0). The point where the objects meet looks pinched. I also need it to have some width (say 0.5mm).

[image]

I have tried adding a few vertices to widen the connection point:

[image]

and it actually looked worse:

[image]

Can someone please help me figure this out? How can I have a smooth wide transition between two shapes connected at one point.

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I found an answer that satisfies what I was trying to do. Thank you very much @josh and all of you guys. (For some reason, the moderator deleted my earlier post saying it wasn't the answer to my very own question). In any case, here it is again.

I created a face where two vertecies meet:
[image]

After adding modifiers, mirror / merge, the final result looks like what I had in mind:

[image]

Thank you all very much.

Answer (score 5):

Your first attempt is uncorrect: as points have no dimensions the mesh is not "Manifold", it can't exist in real life and solidify modifier can't create a proper solid from a single point.

The second version has an ugly "pole": a single vertex with more than 5 edges, which should be always avoided, expecially in theese areas of heavy curvature, and triangles and poligons with more than 4 vertices, avoid them also.

The solution is aim to a all quads topology with smooth transitions and no poles with more than 5 edges.

After creating the correct topology use "Smooth vertices" function and proportional editing to adjust the shape.

[image]

Comment: I'd say that heavy curvature is a problem, but not the single vertex itself... since _Solidify_ doesn't have to generate a thickness from a single vertex which "can't exist in real life", the vertex is an edge point of a face (or two in this case), also non-quads are not a problem in general for the _Solidify_. Here I have tris, quads, n-gons and a single vertex connection between two faces: [Solidify example](https://pasteall.org/pic/7e9a0eebc78a4256928a7a7b88aadd2d) No problem for the modifier. So I guess the heavy curvature is the main reason (if there are no double verts or anything else).

Comment: Josh and Gordon thank you both very much. I learned so much by reading your comments. I started learning Blender 4 weeks ago (come from engineering/Solid-Works background). Then it made sense, in Finite Element Analysis, a single vertex creates a singularity in the model/result. I will pos the final result to the bottom of this thread. Thank you both very much for taking the time and helping me out.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann Kind of.  Apply your solidify modifier, then select non manifold.  After the solidify, the vert is actually a part of 6 faces-- and is part of an edge that connects 4 different faces, a major non-manifold no-no, even though Blender often tries its best to let us get away with that kind of stuff.  Here, also, notice that Aydin's solidify is followed up with a subdivision modifier, and that's an essential part of the problem here.  It's not that a 6-pole or non-quads are so bad for solidify, they're fine; but they aren't going to do CC subdivision the way most people want.

Comment: @Nathan Yes sure, you're correct. I didn't say it would be manifold... you just started off saying _Solidify_ couldn't handle this. As you explain yourself it's more the _Subdivision Surface_ and curvature which make it look weird. So everything's fine with your answer 

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann It's not my answer :)